# how to reset mongoose after using factory girl in test?

Tags: node.js, express, testing, mongoose, factory

I'm using [factory girl](https://github.com/petejkim/factory-lady) for creating my mongoose model instance in javascript. how can I make-instance just in the test environment?

when I use this factory. this method makes my instance really in MongoDB.

```
Factory.create('User', {name: 'WES'}, function(user) {
    // build a post and override title and content
    // console.log(user)
 });
```

***this instance persistence in my DB after runnig test***

```
User.find({ name: 'WES' }, 'name age', function (err, users) {
  // if (err) return handleError(err);
  console.log(users)
})
```

but it must be just in my test environment. I have to reset my mongo DB manually after factory or I can set it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting started with factory girl, but I believe `User.save()` is getting called in `factory.create()`. Try using `factory.cleanUp()` after running your tests.
[See this github issue for more information.](https://github.com/simonexmachina/factory-girl/issues/146)